# Node_modules on publishing a react-bootstrap website

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I'm developing a react-bootstrap website and I'm wondering if I should include the node_modules folder when i will publish the site on a web hosting platform, or there is another way?
I never published before a website with a lot of dependencies

Answer (score 0):

usually it's bad practice to upload node modules! there's no need to upload node_modules folder to server, you can install them using `npm install` or `yarn install` in case your are using yarn. it will create node_modules folder with all the dependencies which you have installed make sure your all dependencies are added in package.json

Comment: Ok, this make sense to me. But npm install is not local? When I upload the project on a server, where do all the bootstrap directories go?

Comment: what do you mean by npm install is not local? if you have installed react-bootstrap using npm then your all bootstrap files are in node_modules and when you upload your project to server you just have to install the dependencies, everything will work.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, is all more clear now

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your approach , if you want to create simple SPA you could run "npm run build" which will give a build folder and once you uploaded those file on the server and point your requsts to index.html
You wont be needing node_modules , BUT having a differant approach , having SSR maybe then yes , you would need to start your project on the server which will need node_modules as well.